# How to manually insert signature in Thunderbird? (impossible?)

Tags: thunderbird, email-signature

How can I manually insert a signature in Thunderbird when I am busy composing an email?
I don't find the option/action in any of the menus (specifically not under Insert, as I would expect).

(**Note**: I know how to configure Thunderbird to *automatically* insert a signature when creating a new mail in a certain account. But if you delete the signature (accidentaly or not), how can you reinsert it? Or how can you insert it for an account which isn't configured to automatically insert a signature?)

Comment: It's a valuable question. As you search for answers to this specific challenge on the web, you see nothing but page after page of rehashed Thunderbird _configuration_ tutorials. And this SuperUser page.

Answer (score 34):

There seems to be a specific reason why the feature 'Insert signature here' is not available in Thunderbird.

This [FAQ entry](http://mozext.achimonline.de/signatureswitch_faq.php#beforequotedtext) from the Thunderbird add-on *Signature Switch* (suggested by Horatio) actually provided me with some insight as to *why* Thunderbird probably doesn't have this feature.

> **FAQ Question: My signature doesn't get removed when
>   it is placed before quoted text. Is
>   that a bug?**
>       No it isn't. ;-)
>       If your Thunderbird is set to place the signature below your reply
>   (above the quote) the removal won't
>   work.That's because Thunderbird then
>   doesn't insert the standard-delimiter
>   ("-- \n") before the signature (for a
>   good reason!). And that's what
>   "Signature Switch" is looking for.
>       Some people might try to bypass that problem by manually adding the
>   sig-delimiter to their signature file.
>   But that will cause another problem.
>       The "-- \n" always marks the very end of a mail-message. "Signature
>   Switch" assumes that any text placed
>   below the signature-delimiter
>   (including any quoted lines) is part
>   of the signature. ... and therefore
>   removes everything below the
>   delimiter.
>       Besides... this option isn't recommended by Thunderbird itself! So
>   please put your signature below your
>   quotings. (check the Wikipedia-excerpt
>   below)

here is the excerpt:

> **From Wikipedia:** " ... The formatting of the sig block
>   is prescribed somewhat more firmly: it
>   should be displayed as plain text in a
>   fixed-width font (no HTML, images, or
>   other rich text), and must be
>   delimited from the body of the message
>   by a single line consisting of exactly
>   two hyphens, followed by a space,
>   followed by the end of line (i.e., "--
>   \n"). ... "

and finally:

> **FAQ Question: I want to place my signature at any
>   desired position within the message.
>   Could you please implement
>   cursor-point-insertion to "Signature
>   Switch"?**
>       Definitely no. Sorry. (And please don't ask me to reconsider.)
>       Due to the reasons explained for the previous question I can't offer
>   you this. Besides... something like
>   that wouldn't have anything to do with
>   "signatures" anymore.
>       If you're looking for an easy way to paste predefined text please check
>   out other extensions especially made
>   for that purpose.

Still, that is all fine and correct from a technical point of view, but usability-wise I just would like to insert my signature where I want.

Answer (score 12):

Hopefully you are using at least two email accounts for Thunderbird. Or at least have another identity to email under. If so, you can just reset the signature by fiddling with the From header.

1. Go to the From field in the Compose window
2. Use the arrow keys to go up (<kbd>↑</kbd>) or down (<kbd>↓</kbd>) the possible identities/accounts to email from

You'll notice as you do this that the relevant signature will be attached to the footer of the email.

Even if you cycle through an email address you're already writing from, the signature will be put back unless you choose to remove it again.

If you only use Thunderbird to email from the one account, you can always [set up a dummy email account](https://superuser.com/questions/178733/changing-the-from-address-in-thunderbird) to allow for the above quick switch method.

If you land on an account that does not have a signature set up, there won't be one waiting for you if you use this method. For that, best go and copy-paste as you cycle in the above steps mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this workaround, but it seems really stupid to do it like this. And it doesn't always work (e.g. when forwarding an email)

Comment: This works for me, without having to install a 3rd party addon +1

Comment: Yikes, ran into this today and sad to hear this is the only workaround. I had accidentally removed the signature block and couldn't figure out how to get it back. I suppose undo could have worked in my case, but even a "reset signature" would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Luckily, thunderbird has an add-on facility. You can go to their 3rd-party add-on page via a link within the program. A quick search immediately brought up:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/611/

PLEASE NOTE that I have NO idea if the linked add-on works or is even safe to use!

Comment: Also this one works https://addons.thunderbird.net/pl/thunderbird/addon/add-signature/

Answer (score 1):

Well, it’s not a fast solution, but you can go

1. <kbd>Main Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Menu</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>Account Settings</kbd> -> Select your Account expander -> <kbd>Signature text:</kbd> -> Select All
2. <kbd>Email Composer Window</kbd> -> Put Cursor where you want the Signature Inserted -> <kbd>Menu</kbd> -> <kbd>Insert</kbd> -> <kbd>HTML...</kbd> -> <kbd>Enter HTML tags and text:</kbd> -> Paste -> <kbd>Insert</kbd>

Voilà, only 15 steps!

<sub>Almost seems like we need a "Ui/UX Golf" stackex site.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is this:

1. Have a signature ready. This can be done in the Thunderbird account settings for the relevant account ('View settings for this account').
2. **Write a new email message. Copy the signature of the new email and paste it into your desired message.**

Alternatively: In the 'Composition & Addressing' section of your account setting tick the relevant signature boxes: 'Include signature for replies'.